# How to define uniqueidentifier column in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a local SQL Server CE database in my Windows Phone 7 app.

Here is the class Employee which holds the properties for the fields that are tables and columns which are used to build the database

I want to:

- change the type of `EmployeeID` from `int` to `uniqueidentifier` and
- make it primary key but I don't know how.

Error:

> `uniqueidentifier` is not recognized (am I missing a library
>   reference?)

```
namespace F5debugWp7LocalDatabase
{
[Table]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EmployeeAge
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `System.Guid` type for `uniqueidentifier` SQL fields.

To make it primary key, add `IsPrimaryKey=true` to the ColumnAttribute definition.

Comment: I added using System.Guid; to my class, and its still doesnt recognize the uniqueidentifier. can you please show me an example of how you define a uniqueidentifier column? thak again

Answer (score 0):

To create my local SQL CE database on windows phone 7 i used LinqToSQL, i generated the database in a separate project then i added it to my Windows Phone project and commented out the two constructors which are not supported in the Windows Phone 7 environment and it works like a charm.

But maybe this will help you too, my ID definitions look like this.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="INT NOT NULL Identity", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```